# Wowslider Conflicting with Lightbox (Slimbox2) Plugin

Tags: slideshow, lightbox, carousel, conflict

I am using two plugins, Wowslider and Slimbox2, together to create a make shift photo album. The two scripts are conflicting and the Slimbox plugin only works on the first album link on the first page load. Once I begin interacting with the wowslider thumbnails to navigate to the albums and click their links the Slimbox breaks.

I have a feeling it has something to do with the JS & rescanning the page but, I am no pro with JS. I use plugins and implement them when needed. Typically I am pretty good at figuring these things out but in this case it is out of my realm of experience. I have done my research and tried to figure this out but no luck.

Here is the URL where the gallery is in development. You will see what I mean when you try to interact with the albums after the first page load.

http://www.vetshouse.org/vth_root/community_photoGallery.html

I am pretty sure my code is fine since it does work on the first album link on the first page load. Which is why I think it is conflicting script.

I have also tried loading the Slimbox2.js before the wowslider scripts and after with no effect.